# installation of package error, non-zero exit status, package not found

Tags: r

I just wanted to install the package "questionr". But the following error keeps occuring. The package that was supposed to be installed cannot be loaded (library(package)) neither I can find the package within the folder 3.5. Never had this problem before.

Do you have any idea whats the matter here? I'd appreciate your help! Thanks

```
   install.packages("questionr")


   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/bisc048/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’, ‘haven’, ‘labelled’


   There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
   binary source needs_compilation
   rlang      0.4.5  0.4.7              TRUE
   vctrs      0.2.4  0.3.4              TRUE
   haven      2.2.0  2.3.1              TRUE
   labelled   2.2.2  2.7.0             FALSE
   questionr  0.7.0  0.7.2             FALSE

   Binaries will be installed
   Warning in install.packages :
   packages ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’ are in use and will not be installed
   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/haven_2.2.0.zip'
   Content type 'application/zip' length 1050152 bytes (1.0 MB)
   downloaded 1.0 MB

   package ‘haven’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

   The downloaded binary packages are in
   C:\Users\bisc048\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUx6QYp\downloaded_packages
   installing the source packages ‘labelled’, ‘questionr’

   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/labelled_2.7.0.tar.gz'
   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 194703 bytes (190 KB)
   downloaded 190 KB

   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/questionr_0.7.2.tar.gz'
   Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1725961 bytes (1.6 MB)
   downloaded 1.6 MB

   * installing *source* package 'labelled' ...
   ** Paket 'labelled' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
   ** R
   ** inst
   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
   Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
   vI[[j]]) : 
   namespace 'haven' 2.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 2.3.1 is required
   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'labelled'
   * removing 'C:/Users/bisc048/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/labelled'
   In R CMD INSTALL
   Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘labelled’ had non-zero exit status
   ERROR: dependency 'labelled' is not available for package 'questionr'
   * removing 'C:/Users/bisc048/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/questionr'
   In R CMD INSTALL
   Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘questionr’ had non-zero exit status

   The downloaded source packages are in
   ‘C:\Users\bisc048\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUx6QYp\downloaded_packages’

   library(questionr)
   Error in library(questionr) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘questionr’
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `questionr` could not be installed because it depends on `labelled`, which failed to install because it depends on `haven` version 2.3.1 or higher, which depends on `rlang` and `vctrs`, which could not be updated because they were in use.

Start a fresh R session with no packages loaded. Use `install.packages()` to update `rlang` and `vctrs` manually. Then update `haven` manually. Then, install `labbelled` manually. Finally, try to install `questionr` again.

If you continue to be unable to update `haven`, browse to your library folder and delete the `haven` folder and install it fresh.

It also looks like you are still using R 3.5. The current R version is 4.0.2. Updating R may help especially if some of the dependencies that failed to install require newer version of R than you are using.